# postgres generate_series performance slower on server then laptop

Tags: postgresql

I have a series of views that build off of each other like this:

rpt_scn_appl_target_v --> rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_v --> rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_timeseries_v --> rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_timeseries_ftprnt_v

In this view..rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_timeseries_v, I use the generate_series function to generate monthly rows between 1/1/2015 and 12/31/2019.

what I've noticed is this:

```
this one takes 10secs to run
select * from rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_timeseries_ftprnt_v where scenario_id = 202

this one takes 9 secs to run:
select * from rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_timeseries_v where scenario_id = 202

this one takes 219msecs to run:
select * from rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_v where scenario_id = 202

this one takes <1sec to run:
select * from rpt_scn_appl_target_v where scenario_id = 202
```

I've noticed that commenting out the `generate_series` code in the view, the query runs in under a second, but with it, it takes 10secs to run...

rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_timeseries_v View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_timeseries_v AS 
 SELECT a.scenario_id,
    a.scenario_desc,
    a.scenario_status,
    a.scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm,
    a.scn_appl_sub_lob_ownr_nm,
    a.scenario_asv_id,
    a.appl_ci_id,
    a.appl_ci_nm,
    a.appl_ci_comm_nm,
    a.appl_lob_ownr_nm,
    a.appl_sub_lob_ownr_nm,
    a.cost,
    a.agg_complexity,
    a.srvc_lvl,
    a.dc_loc,
    a.start_dt,
    a.end_dt,
    a.decomm_dt,
    a.asv_target_id,
    a.asv_target_desc,
    a.asv_target_master,
    a.prod_qty_main_cloud,
    a.prod_cost_main_cloud,
    a.non_prod_qty_main_cloud,
    a.non_prod_cost_main_cloud,
    a.prod_qty_main_onprem,
    a.prod_cost_main_onprem,
    a.non_prod_qty_main_onprem,
    a.non_prod_cost_main_onprem,
    a.prod_qty_target_onprem,
    a.prod_cost_target_onprem,
    a.non_prod_qty_target_onprem,
    a.non_prod_cost_target_onprem,
    a.prod_qty_target_cloud,
    a.prod_cost_target_cloud,
    a.non_prod_qty_target_cloud,
    a.non_prod_cost_target_cloud,
    a.type,
    a.cost_main,
    a.qty_main,
    a.cost_target,
    a.qty_target,
    a.dt,
    a.mth_dt,
        CASE
            WHEN a.type ~~ '%onprem%'::text THEN 'On-Prem'::text
            ELSE 'Cloud'::text
        END AS env_stat,
        CASE
            WHEN a.type ~~ '%non_prod%'::text THEN 'Non-Prod'::text
            ELSE 'Prod'::text
        END AS env,
        CASE
            WHEN a.dt <= a.decomm_dt THEN COALESCE(a.cost_main, 0::double precision)
            WHEN a.decomm_dt IS NULL AND a.end_dt IS NULL AND a.start_dt IS NULL THEN a.cost_main
            ELSE 0::double precision
        END AS cost_curr,
        CASE
            WHEN a.dt <= a.decomm_dt THEN COALESCE(a.qty_main, 0::bigint)
            WHEN a.decomm_dt IS NULL AND a.end_dt IS NULL AND a.start_dt IS NULL THEN a.qty_main
            ELSE 0::bigint
        END AS qty_curr,
        CASE
            WHEN a.dt < a.start_dt THEN 0::bigint
            WHEN a.dt >= a.start_dt AND a.dt < a.end_dt AND a.type ~~ '%non_prod%'::text THEN COALESCE(a.qty_target, 0::bigint)
            WHEN a.dt > a.end_dt THEN COALESCE(a.qty_target, 0::bigint)
            ELSE 0::bigint
        END AS qty_trgt,
        CASE
            WHEN a.dt < a.start_dt THEN 0::double precision
            WHEN a.dt >= a.start_dt AND a.dt < a.end_dt AND a.type ~~ '%non_prod%'::text THEN COALESCE(a.cost_target, 0::double precision)
            WHEN a.dt > a.end_dt THEN COALESCE(a.cost_target, 0::double precision)
            ELSE 0::double precision
        END AS cost_trgt
   FROM ( SELECT t1.scenario_id,
            t1.scenario_desc,
            t1.scenario_status,
            t1.scn_appl_lob_ownr_nm,
            t1.scn_appl_sub_lob_ownr_nm,
            t1.scenario_asv_id,
            t1.appl_ci_id,
            t1.appl_ci_nm,
            t1.appl_ci_comm_nm,
            t1.appl_lob_ownr_nm,
            t1.appl_sub_lob_ownr_nm,
            t1.cost,
            t1.agg_complexity,
            t1.srvc_lvl,
            t1.dc_loc,
            t1.start_dt,
            t1.end_dt,
            t1.decomm_dt,
            t1.asv_target_id,
            t1.asv_target_desc,
            t1.asv_target_master,
            t1.prod_qty_main_cloud,
            t1.prod_cost_main_cloud,
            t1.non_prod_qty_main_cloud,
            t1.non_prod_cost_main_cloud,
            t1.prod_qty_main_onprem,
            t1.prod_cost_main_onprem,
            t1.non_prod_qty_main_onprem,
            t1.non_prod_cost_main_onprem,
            t1.prod_qty_target_onprem,
            t1.prod_cost_target_onprem,
            t1.non_prod_qty_target_onprem,
            t1.non_prod_cost_target_onprem,
            t1.prod_qty_target_cloud,
            t1.prod_cost_target_cloud,
            t1.non_prod_qty_target_cloud,
            t1.non_prod_cost_target_cloud,
            t1.type,
            t1.cost_main,
            t1.qty_main,
            t1.cost_target,
            t1.qty_target,
            generate_series('2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, '2019-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, '1 mon'::interval)::date AS dt,
            to_char(generate_series('2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, '2019-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, '1 mon'::interval)::date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY-MM'::text) AS mth_dt
           FROM rpt_scn_appl_target_unnest_v t1) a;
```

What I've also noticed too is that performance between the database on my laptop and the AWS rds server with the same data, tables, and views..is faster on my laptop even though it has much less ram and cpu. I'm running postgres 9.6 on my laptop and 9.6 on AWS rds. My laptop is macbook pro with 16gb of ram and i7 dual core. For rds, I'm using a m4.4xlarge which is 16 cores and 64gb of ram.

Here is the AWS explain plan:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/UGF

My laptop explain plan:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/zaWt

So I guess my questions are:

1.) why is the query taking longer to run on AWS then my laptop?

2.) anything one can do to speed up generate_series function? Does creating a separate calendar table and then joining to that work faster?

Comment: Off: do you really want to cross join 2 (almost identical) `generate_series()` result sets? Are you sure you don't want to write `generate_series(...)::date dt, to_char(dt::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM'::text) mth_dt` ?

Comment: Note: you probably don't need to_char(). date_trunc() could do what you want.

Comment: Ahh, never mind, I see what could slow you down: put them into the `FROM` clause (and let `mth_dt` to refer to `dt` as in my first comment -- to avoid generate them twice)

Comment: @pozs The subqueryscan at the top looks like a carthesian product (cross join). 1000 is the number of estimated rows from the planner for generate_series(), which doesn't supply estimates to the planner.

Comment: @pozs, I did what you suggested for the second generate, changed it to `to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM')` but still no difference...

Answer (score 0):

1) Your laptop has fewer rows.

```
AWS:  (cost=17,814.33..7,931,812.83 rows=158,200,000 width=527)
Laptop: (cost=15,238.52..4,002,252.94 rows=79,700,000 width=2,030)
```

2) If you are going to use the table several times, is better create a calendar table. 10 years is only 3650 rows, 100 years 36k rows

Comment: tried to join to a calendar table instead of using the generate_series function and the performance was same...here is the explain plan when using a calendar table...https://explain.depesz.com/s/brdw

Comment: create index for `cm.mth_yr` ?

Comment: Did you create the index for `cm.mth_yr` ??